# Mix class and instance variables in module

Tags: crystal-lang

From [github issue #4820](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4820) by [@TPei](https://github.com/TPei).

Hey, I was just wondering if it is possible to mix class and instance variables in a module like in ruby, by using the self.included(base) hook or something similar. Is there any construct that supports this or is anything planned for the future?

To clarify:
In ruby it is possible to define a module (MyFirstModule) and then in another module (MySecondModule) do

```
def self.included(base)
  base.extend(MyFirstModule)
end
```

This then causes the methods in MyFirstModule to become class methods in MySecondModule, thus enabling me to add both class and instance methods when a user includes MySecondModule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer by [@straight-shoota](https://github.com/straight-shoota)

This can be accomplished with the included macro hook: [reference](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/macros/hooks.html)

```
macro included
  extend MyFirstModule
end
```